# Android music service stops when backbutton is pressed

Tags: android, service, back-button

I am working on android code that switches between two different activities.  There is a service that plays music over both of these activities.  The problem is that when i use the back button the service ( the music) stops.  I have done research on the topic i have both onResume and onRestart methods in place....i can't figure out what to do next,any help will be greatly appreciated.  Both activites and service are listed below.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
MusicService myService;
private boolean isBound;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    isBound=false;
    playAudio();

  }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}




public void onButtonClick(View v) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Second_activity.class);

      startActivity(intent);
       onStop();

    ///Intent i= new Intent(this,EmpireShips.class);
   //// startActivity(i);
   //// onStop();
 }



 public void playAudio() {
     Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
     if(!isBound)
     {
     bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
     isBound=true;

     startService(objIntent);
     }
     else
     {
         myService.plauseAudio();

         isBound=false;
         unbindService(myConnection);
     }

 }


 public void stopAudio(View view) {
     Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
     if(isBound)
     {
         isBound=false;
     unbindService(myConnection);   
     stopService(objIntent);

     }
     else
         stopService(objIntent);

 }

 private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {



     public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
             IBinder service) {
         myService = ((MusicService.MyLocalBinder) service).getService();
         isBound = true;
     }

     public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
         isBound = false;
     }

    };

     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
         super.onDestroy();
         if (isBound) {
             // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
             // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
             // now allowed to stop at any time.
             unbindService(myConnection);
             isBound = false;

         }
     }

     public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
         if (isBound) {
              // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
              // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
              // now allowed to stop at any time.
              unbindService(myConnection);
              isBound = false;
              myService.plauseAudio();

         }
     }
```

Second_activity.java

```
public class Second_activity extends Activity {
MusicService myService;
private boolean isBound;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    isBound=false;
    playAudio();



}

public void playAudio() {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
    if(!isBound)
    {
    bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    isBound=true;

    startService(objIntent);
    }
    else
    {
        myService.plauseAudio();

        isBound=false;
        unbindService(myConnection);
    }

}


public void stopAudio(View view) {
    Intent objIntent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
    if(isBound)
    {
        isBound=false;
    unbindService(myConnection);   
    stopService(objIntent);

    }
    else
        stopService(objIntent);

}

private ServiceConnection myConnection = new ServiceConnection() {



    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        myService = ((MusicService.MyLocalBinder) service).getService();
        isBound = true;
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        isBound = false;
    }

   };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (isBound) {
            // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
            // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
            // now allowed to stop at any time.
            unbindService(myConnection);
            isBound = false;

        }
    }

    public void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
         if (isBound) {
             // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
             // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
             // now allowed to stop at any time.
             unbindService(myConnection);
             isBound = false;
             myService.plauseAudio();

         }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
        if (!isBound) {
            // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
            // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
            // now allowed to stop at any time.
         bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
            isBound=true;

         startService(objIntent);
        }
}



    public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
         Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
         if (!isBound) {
             // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
             // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
             // now allowed to stop at any time.
             bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                isBound=true;

         myService.play();
         }

    }








}



     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
         if (!isBound) {
             // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
             // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
             // now allowed to stop at any time.
             bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                isBound=true;

             startService(objIntent);
         }
  }



     public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();
         Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
         if (!isBound) {
              // Disconnect from an application service. You will no longer
              // receive calls as the service is restarted, and the service is
              // now allowed to stop at any time.
             bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                isBound=true;

         myService.play();
         }

     }




}
```

MusicService.java

```
public class MusicService extends Service{

    private static final String LOGCAT = null;
    MediaPlayer AudioPlayer;

    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Service Started!");
        AudioPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.starwars_song);
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        AudioPlayer.start();
        Log.d(LOGCAT, "Media Player started!");
        if(AudioPlayer.isLooping() != true){
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Problem in Playing Audio");
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    public void onStop(){
        AudioPlayer.stop();
        AudioPlayer.release();
    }
    public void onPause(){
        AudioPlayer.stop();
        AudioPlayer.release();
    }
    public void onDestroy(){
        AudioPlayer.stop();
        AudioPlayer.release();
    }
    public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder {
        MusicService getService() {
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }
    private final IBinder myBinder = new MyLocalBinder();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return myBinder;
    }
    public void plauseAudio() {
        if(AudioPlayer.isPlaying())
              AudioPlayer.pause(); 

    }

    public void play() {

              AudioPlayer.start(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: Try to call startService(...) before you call bindService(...) because calling bindService first results in the service shutting down when the Activity is closed.

Comment: [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService) you can see some more information on that issue.

Comment: I tried this...Intent objIntent = new Intent(this,  MusicService.class);
           
           if (!isBound) {
                  
           startService(objIntent);
            bindService(objIntent, myConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
                  isBound=true;
                  
           myService.play();
           }........in my onRestart method.  Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issue on the way you implemented.

1. You have to start the service on activity create (if the service is already running Service.onStartCommand will be called. create MediaPlayer instance only if not null).
2. Bind to the service after the service started in OnCreate to establish the ServiceConnection
3. keep hold of the service instance till the activity is destroyed
4. You can pause the media in onPause if required and start again when onResume.
5. Unbind the service on onDestroy activity.
6. Stop the service if required when exit your application else service will be running. When the application is completely removed from stack, service will also be stopped. You can avoid service been killed, by running your service as Foreground using notification.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete `onDestroy` method in your MusicService and music continues but your service become destroy.